# Node automatically makes session variables?

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

I am using express with the express-session package and can successfully keep a session variable like such,

```
 router.get('/test', function(req, res, next){
  req.session.test = 'awesome';
  res.send('awesome')
})
```

and when I use the code below I will get the desired result

```
router.get('/pest', function(req, res, next){

  res.send(req.session.test)
})
```

I do not have an issue, but I am having trouble understanding, does Node automatically create sessions with other variables? for example:

```
router.get('/test', function(req, res, next){
  router.test = 'test';
  res.send('test')
})
```

then going to

```
router.get('/lest', function(req, res, next){
  res.send(router.test)
})
```

makes the same exact result. It seems odd that node will automatically keep the variable like that after some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't a session variable.

You have a single router object.

Modifications to it will persist for *every* request, not just those that come from a browser with a given session cookie.

Comment: So it needs a state machine to handle all unique ip ?

Comment: Ok to clarify, so changing the router object from person A on a computer in new jersey will result in the change of that same router object in Califronia on computer B logged in with different accounts?

Comment: I don't think a state machine is what you need. You need a session. You shouldn't link sessions of IP addresses (since multiple people can share an IP address), use a session cookie instead. And yes, the router object exists for the whole server, not for the session.